# why should i validate it again grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have this unit test method in grails

```
void "test if login action returns the correct model"() {
        when:"login is called without any parameters(null user) "
        params.max = 0
        def model = controller.login(null)

        then:"it must return an empty user model"
        null == model.user.userName
        null == model.user.password

        when:"login is called with fields with errors"
        params.userName = "ama"
        params.password = "aam"
        def model1 = controller.login()

        then:"it must return a model which has errors"
//        !model1.user.validate() // i commented this out because i want to get rejected values not errors that come from the constraints block
        println model1.user.userName // prints "ama"
        model1.user.hasErrors()
        null != model1.user.errors.getFieldError('password')
        null != model1.user.errors.getFieldError('userName')

        when:"when user is not found"
        params.userName = "amanu"
        params.password = "aam"
        def model2 = controller.login()

        then:"it must return a model with userName field with error"
        "amanu"==model2.user.userName
//        model2.user.hasErrors()
        "user.login.username.not.found"==model2.user.errors.getFieldError('userName').code
    }
```

and this is the login action

```
def login (User user){
        if(user){
            boolean error = false
            if(!user.userName){
                error = true
                user.errors.rejectValue("userName", "user.login.username.empty","User Name can not be empty!")
            }
            if(!user.password){
                error = true
                user.errors.rejectValue("password", "user.login.password.empty","Password can not be empty!")
            }

            if(!error){
                User u = User.findByUserName(user.userName);
                if(!u){
                    //User Name does not exist
                    user.errors.rejectValue("userName", "user.login.username.not.found","User Name was not found!")
                }else if(u?.password != user.password.encodeAsPassword()){
                    //password does not match
                    user.errors.rejectValue("password", "user.login.password.invalid","User Name or Password was Incorrect!")
                }else{
                    //both match here
                    session.user = user
                    if(params.after){
                        if(!params.after.controller){
                            redirect( uri:"/");
                            return;
                        }
                        def action = params.after.action?:'index'
                        redirect controller:params.after.controller, action:action
                        return
                    }
                    redirect uri:'/'
                    return
                    //redirect and return
                }
            }
            //return the user anyways
            return [user: user]
        }else{
            return [user:new User(params)]
        }
    }
```

here is the problem! The above controller successfully sends the correct model to the view and at the view i can successfully check the hasError method and it works without calling the validate method! It shows me the values i rejected!

But when i call `hasErrors()` in the test it returns false! What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question! I finally got what i was doing wrong. I did not pass any parameter to `controller.login()` that means it is being called with null and that will only send out an empty model created by the params ( that is why i got the userName right)!

Therefor when testing actions with a command object (if the command object is a domain) it will only be created if the request is POST it will be null if not found otherwise.

Therefore, while testing remember to pass a parameter! If the command object is not a domain object, the constructor will be called and bindData is called after wards!

Comment: More details on that is available at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects where we describe details like when a new instance is instantiated, when an instance is retrieved from the database, when data binding occurs and for which HTTP request methods, etc.  For example, the rules for data binding on domain class command objects are different for POST, PUT and PATCH vs. all other request methods.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is performed by the framework as part of the request cycle. In a unit test you need to call it explicitly.

It seems to me that you are partially testing you model in the unit test for the controller. Maybe you could move some of the tests to the model unit test? An alternative would be to write an integration test where the whole request cycle is performed. To see that it all sits together.

Comment: "Validation is performed by the framework as part of the request cycle. In a unit test you need to call it explicitly." - That is only correct if you are passing the command object explicitly from the unit test.  If you are populating request parameters and invoking the no-arg version of the controller action method, the framework will create the instance for you and in that case validation is performed, you don't have to do it yourself in the unit test.